# Creating EC2 Access w/ PEM Keys For Other Users

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm indeed new to AWS and EC2, but I'm going to rip my hair out on what should be a simple process.  I have created several server instances.  I can ssh into them with my pem key just fine.  However, when I create a new user through IAM, they can create a keypair that won't allow them to access any of the EC2 instances through SSH.  I can give them full access to EC2, and they still can't login to ssh.  What's the deal here?  Do I actually need to login to each server and create and delete users?  What is the most simple way to create an additional user and then revoke/suspend access?  I'm going to rip my hair out.

Answer (score 1):

IAM is used to give permissions to the AWS APIs. ssh on your server isn't an AWS API. Create ssh key pairs for your users and add the public keys to the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file